# How do we detect that Change Detection is been ran in Angular2 without direct @Output?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, zonejs

Consider the following component tree structure in `Angular2`

```
    A
  B 
D  E
```

If `D` emits an event via click to `B` , `angular2` will automatically start the change detection from root `A`. Is there a way to `console.log` that change detection out even if `D` is not directly emitting event to `A` ?

For example in `D`

`html`

```
<div (click)="update($event)"></div>
```

`component`

```
@Output() myOutputName = new EventEmitter();

update(event) {
    this.myOutputName.emit('some vlaue'); 
}
```

In `B`

```
(myOutputName)="update($event)"
```

But if `B` doesn't further that event I have no way to tell if `A` is running its change detection.

The motivation for this is to figure out which component has `Change Detection` running for debugging purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `ngDoCheck()` on each component.  It is a lifecycle hook that is called every time change detection runs on a component.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck

Note however, that just because the method is called doesn't necessarily mean that the template bindings have been checked for changes.  I believe (I could be wrong, this is from memory, when I played with a plunker a while ago) that even if the first `OnPush` component is not marked,  `ngDoCheck()` is still called, but I don't think the template bindings are checked.  Also, if the `OnPush` component was not marked for check, `ngDoCheck()` is not called on descendant components.